# What object has not been set or referenced properly?

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Call CreateDictFromColumns("Schedule", "A", "B")
Dim dic As Dictionary
Set dic = createdDic
For Each k In dic.Keys
    MsgBox dic(k)
Next
With ListBox1
    .AddItem "test"
End With

End Sub

'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523658/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-take-two-columns-of-data-and-convert-to-dictionary
Function CreateDictFromColumns(sheet As String, keyCol As String, valCol As String) As Dictionary
    Dim aDict As Dictionary
    Set aDict = New Dictionary
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Sheets(sheet).Range(keyCol & ":" & valCol)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long '// for non-adjacent ("A:ZZ")
    lastCol = rng.Columns.Count
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        If (rng(i, 1).Value = "") Then Exit Function
        aDict.Add rng(i, 1).Value, rng(i, lastCol).Value
    Next
    Set createdDic = aDict
End Function
```

I continually get the error "Object Required", and I believe it is coming from Set `dic = createdDic` However I cannot seem to figure out as to why this is wrong. Does this object not need to be set this way, or is it set incorrectly when trying to reference a function as a dictionary? All this code is doing is attempting to create a dictionary as the column being the key, and the row being the value stored. Any additional comments would be useful in understanding a little more on how excel works, along with how declaring a dictionary as a function is handled. Thanks.

Comment: `createdDic` is not a function. You have `CreateDictFromColumns`

Comment: Change the function signature to `Function CreateDic(...`

Comment: He means change it to createdDic

Comment: @DavidZemens This is where I get confused. Then how would I call it to pass in the sheet name and columns? Do I call it and then "Set dic = createdDic"? Im just no understanding exactly how this is working with a function essentially.

Comment: @Tyeler Also now it says Args not optional so refer above to more confusion of mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always be using `Option Explicit` in your modules. This will fail to compile code where variables aren't declared (often the case with typographical errors, etc.)

For example, you have:

```
Set dic = createdDic
```

But, `createdDic` isn't the name of any existing object, object variable, or function which returns an object in the scope of your subroutine `UserForm_Initialize`.

So what this is doing, is interpreting `createdDic` as an undeclared variable of type `Variant` which will, by default, contain an empty string or empty numeric value, which evaluates your expression to:

```
Set dic = ""
```

Or

```
Set dic = Empty
```

This raises the **Object Required** error, because you're attempting to assign a non-object to an object variable.

Possibly confusing you, here you are calling the function (but not returning any value from it):

```
Call CreateDictFromColumns("Schedule", "A", "B")
```

**TO FIX THIS ERROR**

Assign the result of `CreateDictFromColumns` to the `dic` object variable, like so:

```
Set dic = CreateDictFromColumns("Schedule", "A", "B")
```

And ensure the return value before `End Function` is given:

```
Set CreateDictFromColumns = aDict
```

**Putting it all together:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim dic As Dictionary
Set dic = CreateDictFromColumns("Schedule", "A", "B")
For Each k In dic.Keys
    MsgBox dic(k)
Next
With ListBox1
    .AddItem "test"
End With

End Sub

'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523658/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-take-two-columns-of-data-and-convert-to-dictionary
Function CreateDictFromColumns(sheet As String, keyCol As String, valCol As String) As Dictionary
    Dim aDict As Dictionary
    Set aDict = New Dictionary
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Sheets(sheet).Range(keyCol & ":" & valCol)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long '// for non-adjacent ("A:ZZ")
    lastCol = rng.Columns.Count
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        If (rng(i, 1).Value = "") Then Exit Function
        aDict.Add rng(i, 1).Value, rng(i, lastCol).Value
    Next
    Set CreateDictFromColumns = aDict
End Function
```