# Updating Prices from a master list through the workbook VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master price worksheet (Test Price) with product name (col A) and price (col B). I want to create a macro that when you click a button it will update the prices through the entire workbook. The previous person in my position already created a MOD that will update prices throughout the WB if it is changed in one WS. I am trying to link the master list to that code. So loop through the list and update one sheet which will use the existing mod to update all other sheets. Can anyone please help with this?

This is the code that updates the sheets, I need to link the master price list to this:

```
Sub ChangePrice(row As String, price As String)

    Dim cropVal As String: cropVal = Cells(row, 2).Value ' inefficient
    Dim LastRow As Long
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        'simple check for division in A3 (stronger check may be needed)
        If ws.Cells(3, 1).Value = "Division:" Then

            LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

            ' starts in row 12, though data starts in 13
            For i = 12 To LastRow

                'check column 2 if crop is the same
                If ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = cropVal Then

                    'if so, change its price in column 10
                    ws.Cells(i, 10).Value = price

                'this handles situations where the symbol is attached
                ElseIf ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = cropVal & "®" Then

                    ws.Cells(i, 10).Value = price

                End If


            Next i


        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far along with any errors you are encountering.

Comment: I need to know how to loop through the list of values, grab the price and put it in another worksheet with the corresponding product name. I have a snippet of code already that will then update every other sheet. I just don't know how to get prices from the master price list to the first sheet

Comment: On this line `If ws.Cells(3, 1).Value = "Division:" Then` are you looking for an actual error like `#DIV`?

Comment: No that is just to verify the worksheet. All WS that would need to be updated have "Division" in cell A3.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary of the values and then pass the dictionary to the module. You would need to add a For Each loop to your master sheet to find the row with the product for each specific worksheet.

```
Sub CropValFind()
Dim ProdCol As Range, Cell As Range, PriceCol As Range
Set ProdCol = 'Your product column range here
Set PriceCol = 'Your Price Column range here
For Each Cell in ProdCol
    Call ChangePrice(Cell.Value, CreateDictFromColumns("MasterSheetName", ProdCol.Column, PriceCol.Column))
Next
End Sub
```

Assuming your product and price columns are adjacent to each other and the values are strings:

Pulled from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33523909/10462532

```
Function CreateDictFromColumns(sheet As String, keyCol As String, valCol As String) As Dictionary
    Set CreateDictFromColumns = New Dictionary
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Sheets(sheet).Range(keyCol & ":" & valCol)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long '// for non-adjacent ("A:ZZ")
    lastCol = rng.Columns.Count
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        If (rng(i, 1).Value = "") Then Exit Function
        CreateDictFromColumns.Add rng(i, 1).Value, rng(i, lastCol).Value
    Next
End Function
```

Then your ChangePrice Sub would look something like this.

```
Sub ChangePrice(row As String, price As Dictionary)
Dim cropVal As String: cropVal = row 
Dim LastRow As Long
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

'simple check for division in A3 (stronger check may be needed)
If ws.Cells(3, 1).Value = "Division:" Then

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

    ' starts in row 12, though data starts in 13
    For i = 12 To LastRow

        'check column 2 if crop is the same
        If ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = cropVal Then

            'if so, change its price in column 10
            ws.Cells(i, 10).Value = price(row)

        'this handles situations where the symbol is attached
        ElseIf ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = cropVal & "®" Then

            ws.Cells(i, 10).Value = price(row)

        End If


    Next i


End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

A great resource to learn the in's and outs of dictionaries can be found [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/).

Comment: I updated with MOD code. Prices(B) are adjacent to the product(A) and products are in alphabetical order on the master sheet.
I was thinking Loop through master list, find product, price, update existing sheet.
The mod code would then take care of the rest

Comment: I saw. Edited my answer to include your added code.