# How to delete all rows from sheet1 which is not in sheet2

Tags: excel, ms-office, vlookup

friends I have Two Excel Sheets which is shown below...

```
**Sheet_1**           **Sheet_2**
ID  Name  Address      ID Name Address
1    A     Any         2   B     Any
2    B     Any         4   D     Any
3    C     Any         5   E     Any
4    D     Any
5    E     Any
```

I want to delete all rows from Sheet_1 which is not in Sheet_2.

**Note:** ID of sheets is unique

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have a sheet_1 which has 27000 records and  sheet_2 which has 600 record only, some of the sheet_2 record is not exist in sheet_1 so i want to delete these records from sheet_2

Comment: Use `MATCH()` on sheet 1 to check if the ID exists on sheet 2 - sort and delete the error results.

Comment: ... or use Power Query and merge the two tables with the desired join type ...

Comment: Remember to mark as the answer if that solved tour problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got this right, but you want to delete rows that are not in `Sheet2`?

So that would make your `Sheet1` to be a copy of `Sheet2`, wouldn't it?

Well, anyways, here is the code of the main `Sub`:

```
Sub Main()
Set idsToExclude = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"): idsToExclude.CompareMode = TextCompare
'fill dictionary with IDs from sheet 2
Set idsToExclude = CreateDictFromColumns("Sheet2", "A", "B")
'find last populated row
xEndRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'iterate all rows from bottom to top
For i = xEndRow To 2 Step -1
    'get value of cell at current row and 1st column
    currentCellValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
    'if row doesnt met criteria, delete it
    If Not idsToExclude.Exists(currentCellValue) Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If

Next
End Sub
```

And the `Function` to get the Ids and names from a specific `Sheet`:

```
Function CreateDictFromColumns(sheet As String, keyCol As String, valCol As String) As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"): dict.CompareMode = TextCompare
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long '// for non-adjacent ("A:ZZ")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sheets(sheet).Range(keyCol & Sheets(sheet).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Sheets(sheet).Range(keyCol & "1:" & valCol & lastRow)
    lastCol = rng.Columns.Count
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If (rng(i, 1).Value = "") Then Exit Function
        dict.Add rng(i, 1).Value, rng(i, lastCol).Value
    Next
    Set CreateDictFromColumns = dict
End Function
```

**Note:** If you want to make the contrary (delete IDs in `Sheet1` that are in `Sheet2`), just remove the `Not` Operator from the following line:

```
If Not idsToExclude.Exists(currentCellValue) Then
```

As you can see, some parts are hard-coded. My suggestion is to adapt those parts and make it more dynamical, I had to write it like that due to lack of details in question.

Comment: I got the `Function` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523658/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-take-two-columns-of-data-and-convert-to-dictionary), and modified it a little.